# Environment variables not loaded on Ubuntu 14.04 VPS Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04, rbenv

this is driving me crazy for a few days now and I can't figure out how to solve this. I am new to this so it might just be something very simple.

I set up my VPS hosting on Ubuntu 14.04 using Digital Ocean to deploy my Rails 4 app to a production environment. I deployed my app using Capistrano and Nginx by following this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma

The only problem that I currently have is that my environment variables are not loaded by my app. Or at least, when I try to subscribe to my newsletter, it tells me that a valid api key is required.

What I did so far:

- Installed rbenv-var as instructed in the documentation.
- Created a .rbenv-var file in my /appname/current folder
- When I run rbenv vars, everything looks OK
- ran source ~/.bash_profile (found this somewhere that could solve the problem, but it didnt)
- Tried "spring stop" as indicated somewhere but didn't work either. Spring was not installed
- I also tried adding my variables to my ~/.bashrc file, that didn't work either
- Tried adding them to my ~/.bash_profile file, ran source ~/.bash_profile but that didn't work either.

This is my bash_profile file:
    [[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM$
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
export MAILCHIMP_API_KEY="somenumber"
export MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID="somenumber"
```

Happy to add any extra code if required.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem, everything you mentioned above. Here's what I did:

In `~/.profile` on your ubuntu box make sure you are loading **both** `.bashrc` && `.bash_profile`

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  # include .bashrc if it exists
  if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
  fi
  if [-f "$HOME/.bash_profile" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bash_profile"
  fi
fi
```

Then, make sure your environment variables are exported from your `.bash_profile`.

```
# .bash_profile
export KEY=value
etc.
```

Restart your server (in my case, I was running nginx, so `sudo service nginx restart`), then restart your app (`touch app/current/tmp/restart.txt`).

Your app should have access to the env variables now.

Comment: Thanks for comment! So variables are stored in .bash_profile file only?

Comment: It's worked for me after following as above code. Thanks!!

Comment: I guess environment variables are stored in `.bash_profile` on ubuntu boxes, but I'm not a sys admin nor am I an expert in Ubuntu. I just know this works! if this works for you and answers the question, please mark it as the correct answer.